# Deserializing dictionary with custom class keys fail in PyYAML

Tags: python, pyyaml

I was trying to use PyYAML to serialize a dictionary which uses instances of `SampleClass` as keys. It serializes OK, but when I am trying to load it with `yaml.load()`, it raises an exception:

> AttributeError: 'SampleClass' object has no attribute 'name'

How can this be fixed?
The `SampleClass` looks **like this:**

```
import uuid

class SampleClass:

    def __init__(self, name = "<NO NAME>"):
        self.objects = []
        self.name = name
        self.id = uuid.uuid1()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SampleClass):
            return self.name == other.name and \
                self.objects == other.objects and \
                self.id == other.id
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((str(self.name), str(self.id)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyYAML is a bit outdated, it only supports YAML 1.1 which has been superseded by YAML 1.2 
back in 2009. Also note that although PyYAML can *parse* complex keys in YAML mappings (e.g. keys that are sequences or mappings themselves), keys that are valid in YAML, it fails on constructing them in Python, effectively not being able to load these.

With `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), you can simply do:

```
import sys
import uuid
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

class SampleClass:

    def __init__(self, name = "<NO NAME>"):
        self.objects = []
        self.name = name
        self.id = uuid.uuid1()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SampleClass):
            return self.name == other.name and \
                self.objects == other.objects and \
                self.id == other.id
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((str(self.name), str(self.id)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "SampleClass({})".format(self. name)

data = {SampleClass("abc"): 1, SampleClass("xyz"): 42}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ="unsafe")
buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(data, buf)
x = yaml.load(buf.getvalue())
print(x)
```

which gives:

```
{SampleClass(abc): 1, SampleClass(xyz): 42}
```

I do recommend however to provide `to_yaml` and `from_yaml` routines
to `SampleClass` and registering the class
([doc](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html)). This
allows you to do away with the unsafe loading (which is BTW the
default for PyYAML).